# I have no extension=* statements in my php.ini yet they load. How?

Tags: apache2, php

How are my php extensions loading if there are no extension=* statements in my php.ini? Does it just automatically load everything in my /conf.d/ directory? I can even find the path to /conf.d/ specified in php.ini.

Comment: OK I just accepted the first answer on all the questions I had not accepted becuase they were bogus, but there weren't any better answers available. I'm sure that is not how the site intended it to be used , but since it reflects poorly on me not to do so, I did.

Comment: @EliahKagen So why can't they change it so that it doesn't count against you.

Comment: I recommend posting on [meta](http://meta.askubuntu.com/) if you want more information about this topic (search first).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the `php5` packages will automatically pull ***all*** configurations in the `conf.d` directory.  I don't remember where in the configurations, but there's a directive to include all configurations in the `/etc/php5/conf.d` directory.  That's why the extension packages such as `php5-gd` install the libraries, and then also install a conf file to the `conf.d` directory, then restarts php5, and pulls the data from there.

Comment: I have had to dissect the `php5` source package on occasion, I ran into this as a result of my having to dissect the package.